# Set Up Router for LAN?

Tags: router, lan

I have a TP Link Router and I want to use for connecting all my computers to each other as a LAN network, not for accessing internet. Now I don't want to connect a LAN cable to my laptop from router, so is there any way to access router wirelessly and set it up? Also, I need the step by step process of setting up the router, I an very new to all this.

Answer (score 1):

Usually there are quick-start guides to do this. It sounds like all you actually need to do is set up wireless security. It can be done wireless, but it's more of a pain, and will force you to disconnect once or twice.

**Edit - As you've now provided your router model, [these](http://www.tp-link.com/Resources/document/7106503703_TD-W8951ND_QIG.pdf) instructions are specific to your router. Use `Method 2` from Page 4 onwards, skip the `Internet Parameters Configuration` and go to `Wireless Settings Configuration` on page 7. Use WPA2-PSK and TKIP/AES for your Wireless Authentication type and Encryption**

Note - these instructions are fairly generic for TP-Link, your model may vary slightly but the general set up should be similar.

1. If this isn't your first time using the router, reset it to default settings by powering it on and pressing a reset switch at the back (usually recessed into the plastic, you may need a pin to do it).

[image]

2. On the underside of your router it'll usually list the default SSID, IP Address, username, and password. Either way, it'll normally start broadcasting an open SSID, usually TP_LINK####. Connect to this network.
3. Go to your web browser and enter the IP address from the underside of the router. If you can't find it, open a command prompt (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> -> `cmd`) and type `ipconfig`. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Look for your wireless network. Enter the 'default gateway' into your browser.

[image]

4. You should be greeted with a request for a username and password. This will either be the details from the underside of your router, or the defaults for TP Link are often `admin` and `admin`.
5. Assuming you've succeeded this far, go to `Wireless`, then `Wireless Settings`. Enter an SSID you wish to use and save it. This will likely disconnect you, and you'll have to reconnect to your network with its new SSID.
6. Repeat the steps to get back to the admin page. Go to `Wireless`, then `Wireless Security`.

[image]

7. The image shows WEP with a red box around it, ignore that, don't use a WEP key (you might as well not be using security). Choose WPA2, and enter a PSK. This will be your wireless password. Save your settings (again, you'll be kicked off).
8. You're now pretty much done. You should go back on and change your Admin password, otherwise anyone on your network can change these settings.

Answer (score 0):

Some home routers doesn't allow to be configured via wireless. You need to check router's manual.

Comment: Ok, is it possible that I just connect it once for configuration and then use it wirelessly on all my computers?

Comment: Yes. Do you have any issues with that?

Comment: I don't know how to do it, can you give me some info

Comment: Provide exact model of your router and i'll try to help you to configure it.

Comment: It's TD-W8951ND

Comment: I dont have enough rep, to comment other's posts

Comment: If you post non-answers, they will attract downvotes, which will eat into your rep and delay your ability to comment.  You're a few points away.  Just defer helping on questions for which you don't yet have the rep to post appropriately.  The site has a huge user base.  Others will pick up the slack in the meantime.